# How to parse some text from pattern with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

the string contains a value like this:

```
my string [[ [[test1]] test2 ]] other text
```

How I can get a values `test1` and `test2` in a different variables?

**I tried!**

```
var test = "my string [[ [[test1]] test2 ]] other text";

var reg = /[^\[\]]*[\w ]+(?=\])/i;
var reg2 = /\]\]\s*(.*)\s*\]\]/i;

result = reg2.exec(test);

​alert(result);​
```

The second regular I've made by myself, but it's still not the answer, it's returns me an array. So how to make it only a one value instead of whole array?

Comment: ok, where I can read about what I can to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regular experssion `[^\[\]]*[\w ]+(?=\])`

Comment: Why are you just giving answers away? They haven't even shown any effort.

Comment: sorry, I even doesn't know what better to use, I know that javascript has not only a RegExp functions to make it.